# Repeating same element pattern in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I want to make a custom layout, which will hold images and repeat same layout over and over again till there no elements left. Each square represents an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter. Inside your view binding you would inflate your custom layout and bind it to the element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` to view list items and use `RecyclerView.Adapter` as its adapter. Make a separate layout for one set of items (in your case: 4 images in `TableView`) and use this layout as item of your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView to have this kind of layout. Inside **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** take "Image 1" , "Image 2" , "Image 3"  & "Image 4" by findViewById. Then inside your  RecyclerView.Adapter make one method such as

```
 public void dataBind()
 {
 //store your  four images data here
 notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
   //bind your four images data to viewholder which contains holder for four images
   holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
   holder.label1.setText(mDataset.get(Position+1).getText2());
   holder.label3.setText(mDataset.get(position+2).getmText3());
   holder.label4.setText(mDataset.get(Position+3).getText4());
}
```